# Protocol Error (71) is comming from usbtest driver while reading bulk in request from USB device

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver

I have ubuntu 12.04 with kernel version 3.2.0 on my Linux PC.

I have updated one usbtest driver for my USB device which is working fine in vendor read and write request.

I have also requirement to read bulk in request which can used to read 4 bytes of data from USB device.

I got the error like **Protocol Error (71)** continuously while reading bulk in request data and the it can not be recovered after unloading and loading my usbtest driver.

To recover that error, I have to unplug and plug the udb device then and then i can do vendor read/write request after getting that error.

Is there any one have idea about how to resolve that issue or is any one have faced this type of issue before?

Please let me know the positive feedback as soon as possible.

ioctl error :: 71 (Protocol error)
ioctl called failed status :: -1

Comment: Is there any one have idea about this type of error? Please let me know as quickly as possible if any have faced this  type of problem.

Comment: Is any one have idea  about timing (delay) constraint required to cause this type of error? Because I have observed one  thing that whenever i put some debug  statement in usbetst driver while fetching bulk in request at that this type of error is not faced from usbtest driver. But Whenever I removed that debug statement at that time this protocol error is coming again.

Comment: Error is like "Protocol error (POSIX.1)".

Comment: why any one is not doing response to my above question?? Please let me reply as soon as possible if any one knows the answer of this question.